# Swiping Gallery in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, swipe

I'm developing app and want a gallery with three images on my page.
I want to change the images while swiping.
I want page to look something like this:

[image]

I think CarouselPage doesnot work here,because I want only to swipe the images,but the buttons should stay nested.
I Saw some posts about CarouselView,but could not find how to use it.

Do you have any ideas how to create the page like this?
Also I want it for cross-platforms.

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/CarouselView

Comment: @Akash Amin the links on the page does not work :(

Comment: They do work. I checked.

Comment: Carousel Implementation and Xamarin labs example it says that page not found :(